# Is the number of sequences of natural numbers (without any restriction) countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the number of sequences of natural numbers (without any restriction) countable?

I suspect it isn't countable, but I can't think of how to prove it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it is not. To see this, note that there's an injection from the set of non-terminating decimal expansions of real numbers between 0 and 1 into it by sending $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ to $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$. Since $(0,1)$ is uncountable, so is your set. Alternatively, you can echo Cantor's diagonal argument in your set.

Comment: Thank you , i didn't remember this proof. you're so helpfull.